# How I can remove not related to render data?

Tags: reactjs

How can I remove arrays from the render that, in fact, should not be there (commitsContentValues, membersContentValues, commitsValue, memberValue) and move it to separate methods. How can I make my code cleaner? And in which chapter of the reсt documentation is it described?

```
    export default class Content extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          iteams: {},
        };
      }
    
      async componentDidMount() {
       membersData = 123
commitsData =zxc
          this.setState({
            iteams: { membersData, commitsData },
          });
        } catch {
          console.log(err);
    }
      render() {
        const { iteams } = this.state;
    
        const commitsContentValues = {    //this 
          firstRowText: "Date",
          secondRowText: "Author",
          thirdRowtext: "Commit Message",
          firstRowKey: "committed_date",
          secondRowKey: "author_name",
          thirdRowkey: "title",
        };
        const membersContentValues = {       //this 
          firstRowText: "Username",
          secondRowText: "Name",
          thirdRowtext: "GitLab Id",
          firstRowKey: "username",
          secondRowKey: "name",
          thirdRowkey: "id",
        };
        const commitsValue = {            //this 
          dataKey: "commitsData",
          arrKey: "commits",
        };
        const memberValue = {            //this 
          dataKey: "membersData",
          arrKey: "members",
        };
        return (
          <div>
            {this.props.idx === 0 && (
              <BasicTable
                commits={iteams.commitsData}
                commitsData={commitsContentValues}
                keys={commitsValue}
              ></BasicTable>
            ...
```

Comment: @PeterSmith Yes

Comment: Throw them out of the component scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to just have the values you want returned from a function as you said:

```
export default class Content extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      iteams: {},
    };
  }

  function getCommitsContentValues() {
      return {
          firstRowText: "Date",
          secondRowText: "Author",
          thirdRowtext: "Commit Message",
          firstRowKey: "committed_date",
          secondRowKey: "author_name",
          thirdRowkey: "title",
        };
      }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <BasicTable
          commitsData={this.getCommitsContentValues()}
        ></BasicTable>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Is this what you are trying to do?